# I am getting this error "TypeError: app.get is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 80;

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{ 
    res.send("This is homepage of my first express app with Harry");
});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`The application started successfully on port ${port}`);
});
```

I am practicing express in node as a beginner and wrote this code, can't figure it out why is it showing **typeerror: app.get is not a function**

Comment: This code is perfectly working. Try to rerun again. Or may be you are cheking on wrong URL or it can be Port error...try to change port to 5000 and check again...Thank you...!

Comment: "typeerror: app.get is not a function" is a mini nightmare of mine, and it typically doesn't happen because my express code has an error, but elsewhere.

Comment: Can you show the full error stack?

Comment: @BhargavGarnara Thank you buddy! I'll try to change port and will check again.

Comment: @Asphodel Haha same! I sometimes get so exausted.